# Laravel Project on Pleask except homepage other routes are not working

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, server

I uploaded files of my Laravel project at Plesk server in httpdocs folder and change necessary permission. Now my homepage is working fine but other routes showing 404 server error ( see screenshot [http://prntscr.com/h54nra][1])

For checking few solutions in different forums and at stackoverflow I also tried to make changes in my .htaccess file but yet unable to resolve.
Currently I am using following code hor .htaccess file which is working fine on my localhost

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Let me know if you find any solution for this

Comment: How you put your code on the server? So for now your app should access it with `public`: `http://appurl.com/public`?

Comment: I have my index.php file in root directory so no need to add /public, app working at root directory showing homepage : http://appurl.com. 
But further router showing 404 say : http://appurl.com/about is not working

Comment: Is your server using apache? Or nginx instead?

Comment: server using Microsoft-IIS/8.5

Comment: So you run `php` under `Microsoft-IIS/8.5`  with `php` module right? Anyway `.htaccess` file just for apache. It won't work under `IIS` nor `nginx`.  You issue is the url rewriting. I'm sorry can't help more, because I never try run Laravel app under `IIS`. I've ever been deploy my Laravel app in Windows, but I install `apache` to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using IIS, .htaccess is not involved into redirects to open any of sub-pages except the main page. Instead, redirects should be specified in domain's web.config file, for example:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="index.php" />
            <add value="default.aspx" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="index.htm" />
            <add value="index.html" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
```

This file should be placed in domain's httpdocs or httpdocs/public folder, depending on the project configuration. 
The following tutorials may provide some other details regarding setting up Laravel in IIS: [here](http://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/) and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5)

Comment: I added this file web.config with this code , Now I am getting 500 error (sceenshot : http://prntscr.com/h58s02)

Comment: I added web.config file, Homepage is showing but for other pages I am getting error msg "The requested document was not found on this server.".

Comment: Finally It works, I added code in web.config file from the source you provided http://jimfrenette.com/2016/09/laravel-iis-windows-install/ and it strted working now, My homepage (app.com) and other pages (app.com/registration etc..) are working fine now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem in my Plesk server, MY project was done in Laravel. So, I have edited two major files to solve this problem. Please find the below changes.

```
i) public -> web.config : 

{
<!--
Rewrites requires Microsoft URL Rewrite Module for IIS
Download: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite
Debug Help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite- 
module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules
-->
<configuration>


<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
  </configuration>

}


ii) public -> .htaccess 

{

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).